# How to re-seal rough-in bit in basement bath?

Tags: plumbing, basement, rough-in

I'm finishing a basement, and a bathroom shower drain rough in was pit was sealed with a plywood top. Now, the drain had to be moved a bit, so we cut the plywood to get access to the piping below, and moved a pipe 6 inches or so.

Do I need to seal it all back somehow, or can I leave it as-is? The opening will be partly in interior wall cavity, and partly under the shower acrylic base, so not visible, and no flooring will be above it.

We are in southern Ontario, this is a fairly new house, and everything in the basement concrete floor was sealed/caulked by the builder: sump pump, post bases, etc.

Comment: Without photos and a little editing of your question, this will be difficult to answer. Please edit the question; the part about "the pit" isn't clear. Add well-lit photos of all the specific areas you're asking about.

Comment: I think you are supposed to seal it because of insects